# Use Bash's extended globbing to negate a filename that begins with a dot

Tags: bash, wildcards

Let's say I have this files:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$ tree -F -C -a .
.
├── .git/
├── ss/
├── y
└── !yes/

3 directories, 1 file
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$
```

Negate the `!yes` is working fine by escape the `!` with `\`:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$ mkdir /tmp/aaa/webview2; cp -r -a !(\!yes) /tmp/aaa/webview2                                         
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$ l /tmp/aaa/webview2
total 16K
39331773 -rw-rw-r-- 1 xiaobai xiaobai ?    0 Jul  27 05:07 y
39331771 drwxrwxr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:43 .git/
39331772 drwxrwxr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:43 ss/
39331757 drwxrwxr-x 4 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:44 ../
39331770 drwxrwxr-x 4 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:44 ./
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$
```

But `!(.git)` not working:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp/test/hello$ rm -r /tmp/test; shopt -s extglob; shopt -s dotglob; mkdir -p /tmp/test/hello; mkdir /tmp/test/hello2; cd /tmp/test/hello; mkdir '.git'; cp -r -a !(.git) /tmp/test/hello2/; ls -la /tmp/test/hello2/
cp: will not create hard link '/tmp/test/hello2/hello' to directory '/tmp/test/hello2/.'
cp: cannot copy a directory, '..', into itself, '/tmp/test/hello2/'
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 4 xiaobai xiaobai 4096 Jul  27 16:05 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 xiaobai xiaobai 4096 Jul  27 16:05 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai 4096 Jul  27 16:05 .git
drwxrwxr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai 4096 Jul  27 16:05 hello2
xb@dnxb:/tmp/test/hello$
```

Escape `.` with `\` not working:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$ rm -r /tmp/aaa/webview2
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$ mkdir /tmp/aaa/webview2; cp -r -a !(\.git) /tmp/aaa/webview2        
cp: will not create hard link '/tmp/aaa/webview2/webview' to directory '/tmp/aaa/webview2/.'
cp: cannot copy a directory, '..', into itself, '/tmp/aaa/webview2'
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$ l /tmp/aaa/webview2                                         
total 24K
39331773 -rw-rw-r-- 1 xiaobai xiaobai ?    0 Jul  27 05:07 y
39331774 drwxrwxr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:39 !yes/
39331775 drwxrwxr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:39 webview2/
39331771 drwxrwxr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:43 .git/
39331772 drwxrwxr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:43 ss/
39331757 drwxrwxr-x 4 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:44 ../
39331770 drwxrwxr-x 6 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:44 ./
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$
```

Double slash `\\` not working either:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$ rm -r /tmp/aaa/webview2
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$ mkdir /tmp/aaa/webview2; cp -r -a !(\\.git) /tmp/aaa/webview2
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$ l /tmp/aaa/webview2
total 20K
39331773 -rw-rw-r-- 1 xiaobai xiaobai ?    0 Jul  27 05:07 y
39331774 drwxrwxr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:39 !yes/
39331771 drwxrwxr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:43 .git/
39331772 drwxrwxr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:43 ss/
39331757 drwxrwxr-x 4 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:44 ../
39331770 drwxrwxr-x 5 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:44 ./
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$
```

And I found this working:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$ rm -r /tmp/aaa/webview2
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$ mkdir /tmp/aaa/webview2; cp -r -a !(.git|.|..) /tmp/aaa/webview2
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$ l /tmp/aaa/webview2
total 16K
39331772 -rw-rw-r-- 1 xiaobai xiaobai ?    0 Jul  27 05:07 y
39331773 drwxrwxr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:39 !yes/
39331771 drwxrwxr-x 2 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:43 ss/
39331757 drwxrwxr-x 4 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:45 ../
39331770 drwxrwxr-x 4 xiaobai xiaobai ? 4.0K Jul  27 05:45 ./
xb@dnxb:/tmp/aaa/webview$
```

Why direct escape dot not working ? And what's the proper way to negate in this case ? (I doubt `!(.git|.|..)` will get unexpected result in some cases).

Note that I know `rsync` can be used to exclude, but it's not my question.

**[UPDATE]**

I did enabled extglob and dotglob for my test case, they're not the cause.

I think the reason of `!(.git)` failed is because of `.` and `..` error and abort, not because of `.git` expansion was failed. And `!(.git|.|..)` should be the correct way already.

Comment: Might be worth saying that you've got `shopt -s extglob` enabled for the `!` negation operator to be recognised. None of my `bash` shells has that enabled by default.

Comment: @roaima yes, I've enabled extglob.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clearer what you're asking; 3 people had voted to close this for being unclear but I figured a more descriptive title should be enough to clarify the intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash`, without the `dotglob` option, hidden files are ignored unless the glob *explicitly* (that is with a literal leading `.`) asks for them. And `.` and `..` are not ignored (contrary to what more sensible shells like `pdksh`, `zsh` or `fish` do).

With `dotglob`, only `.` and `..` are ignored unless the glob starts with `.`.

With `extglob`, `bash` adds support for some of `ksh` extended glob operators. However, here with a bug/misfeature when it comes to the `!(...)` one.

In both `ksh` (though not `pdksh`) and `bash`, `@(.*)` is one case where you explicitly request  dotfiles (though the documentation doesn't make that clear).

But in `!(.git)` you're not requesting dotfiles. `ksh` and `zsh` in `ksh` emulation handle it correctly, but `bash` presumes you're requesting dotfiles. And that includes `.` and `..` even with `dotglob`. So `.git` will be copied as part of the copying of `.`.

To work around that, you can use `!([.]git)` (here `[.]` makes the `.` not explicit) in combination with `dotglob`, or exclude `.` and `..` explicitly with `!(.git|.|..)`:

```
$ bash -O extglob -c 'echo !(.git)'
. .. foo .foo
$ bash -O extglob -O dotglob -c 'echo !(.git)'
. .. foo .foo
$ bash -O extglob -O dotglob -c 'echo !([.]git)'
foo .foo
$ bash -O extglob -c 'echo !(.git|.|..)'
foo .foo
```

In the latter case, I would still add the `dotglob` option because `bash` in a future version may be fixed to stop including dotfiles here like in other shells.

As I use `zsh` which has its own extended operators (with the `extendedglob` option not enabled by default to keep Bourne compatibility; it also supports ksh globs with the `kshglob` option but those are more awkward), I'd do:

```
set -o extendedglob # (in my ~/.zshrc)
cp -a -- ^.git(D) target/
```

(note that `-a` implies `-r` and you need the `--` as we can't guarantee file names won't start with `-`).

`^.git` is `zsh`'s equivalent of ksh's `!(.git)`. `(D)` to include dotfiles (but never `.` nor `..`) for that glob only.

Comment: Thanks, is there any documentation mentioned about `[.] makes the . not explicit` ?

Comment: @林果皞, the doc says that `.` must be named explicitly. `?`, `*`, `[^x]`, `[.]` match a dot but are not an explicit dot. Still `@(.)` is not `.` either, but `@(.)*` still matches dotfiles, so the documentation is incomplete on that front.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the shell don't include '.' in expansion of wildcards. Run `shopt -s dotglob` which enables the shell expansion to include '.'

```
dotglob
    If set, Bash includes filenames beginning with a ‘.’ in the results of 
    filename expansion.
```

[Shopt builtin man page](http://www.dba86.com/docs/gnu/bash/bash.html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)

Comment: I've enabled dotglob but `.git` still exist in the destination directory.

Comment: I've tested it with `cp -r -a !(.filename) folder` and it works as expected on bash 4.2. On what OS are you running it? and what is the bash version you use?

Comment: Don't you still see `.git` when test with `shopt -s extglob; shopt -s dotglob; mkdir -p /tmp/test/hello; mkdir /tmp/test/hello2; cd /tmp/test/hello; mkdir '.git'; cp -r -a !(.git) /tmp/test/hello2/; ls -la /tmp/test/hello2/` ? Bash version is `GNU bash, version 4.4.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` in ubuntu 17.04. I'm curious why you don't encounter .. error.

Comment: Oh I see, you should put .git in `'.git'`, this would work.

Comment: `!('.git')` not working.

Comment: As I've mentioned, `!(.git)` itself is working, but this is failed because of `.` and `..` need to exclude explicitly, but I'm still curious why you don't encounter such error.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work for you, it works without errors for me when I exclude the file I want + the destination directory, `# cp -r -a !('.viminfo'|'bla') bla/` - as my dest. dir is bla/

Comment: Did you tried the command above ? `shopt -s extglob; shopt -s dotglob; mkdir -p /tmp/test/hello; mkdir /tmp/test/hello2; cd /tmp/test/hello; mkdir '.git'; cp -r -a !(.git) /tmp/test/hello2/; ls -la /tmp/test/hello2/`

Comment: I suspect is because of bash version difference, I just tested with the online terminal at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php but no such error.